# Jssor Slideshow Not Fading in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jssor

Thanks in advance for any help on this.  I am using a basic Jssor fading slideshow.  It works fine on Firefox, IE, and Safari, but the images won't fade in Chrome, they just transition directly from one image to the next.  I can't figure out where I've gone wrong, and I'm not familiar enough with javascript to be able to troubleshoot in more depth.  Here is a link to the work in progress: http://www.angelabrowndesign.com/salmon_river_brewery/index.php.

Here is the code that's within the body tag for the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [{
            $Duration: 2000,
            $Delay: 40,
            $During:{$Left:[0.6,0.8]},
            $FlyDirection: 2,
            $Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear},
            $ScaleHorizontal:0.3,
            $Opacity: 2 }];

        var options = {
            $DragOrientation: 3,
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $SlideDuration: 2000,
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4500,
            $SlideshowOptions: {        //Options which specifies enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,   //Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions, //Transitions to play slide, see jssor slideshow transition builder
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,     //The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: 2,                     //0 After Slideshow, 2 Always
                $ContentMode: false                             //Whether to trait content as slide, otherwise trait an image as slide
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE: I have been able to tweak the javascript so that I am getting a fade effect in Chrome.  However, now (again, only in Chrome), there is this period between images, where no image appears at all, just the page background, and then the new image sort of "jolts" into the frame.  It's not nearly as smooth as the other browsers.  Here's the updated relevant code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/modernizr.custom.13935.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
    //Fade
        {$Duration:700,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1000,$Opacity:2}}
        ];
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = {
                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2          vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
});
</script>

<header class="pageHeader cf">
<div id="slides">
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 785px; height: 305px;">

        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(/salmon_river_brewery/js/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 785px; height: 305px;">
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header3.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header4.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header1.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header5.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header2.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
</div></div></div>
</header>
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get a helpful answer if you post the code that isn't working in your question.

Comment: Edit your question to contain the code, using the code formatting (four spaces at the beginning of each line).

Comment: Got it now.  Sorry, this is my first time posting to this forum.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use <div></div> to define slide.

Please replace

```
<img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header3.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" />
<img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header4.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" />
<img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header1.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" />
<img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header5.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" />
<img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header2.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" />
```

with

```
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header3.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header4.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header1.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header5.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
<div><img src="/salmon_river_brewery/images/image-header2.jpg" width="785" height="305" class="slideshow" /></div>
```

Also, the following code is no need in your page.

```
<script src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script src="/salmon_river_brewery/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

Btw, it's highly recommended to download the latest version (performance is much better).

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  I made the changes you recommended.  However, still not working in Chrome.  I am not sure what you mean by latest version.  Chrome is up to date on my computer and just to make sure, I re-downloaded the latest jssor files and uploaded those.  If there is something else out date, let me know.

Comment: Please download the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly which troubleshooting solution fixed my problem.  However, I believe that I had not uploaded something from the jssor files that caused the problem in Chrome.
I wasn't clear from the instructions which files were necessary, so I might have missed one.